# How to get logging information in Talend

Tags: logging, error-handling, talend

I am trying to get logging of talend jobs (eg. no. of rows processed, no. of rows committed start_time_of_job, end_time_of_job etc.) How do I'll get this information?

I'm using `Talend 6.1`. I've enabled `tLogCatcher`, `tStatCatcher`, `tFlowMeterCatcher` in PROJECT SETTINGS but that's giving me logging details after completion of the job.

If I am running job through command line and if I want to check logging then I won't be able to get that information.

How I'll get this information? tLogCatcher only writes data in the file or table if any error occurred. But if job completed successfully then it don't write any information to the log file.

Please help me to tackle this issue.

Comment: FlowMeter will only give you results once the flow completes. If you have access to kibana/logstash then I'd configure a log4j appender and then you'd get more realtime results. Personally I use like and use both approaches. If you run it through commandline you should get that information.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I'll try that.

Comment: you can also trigger a tWarn post your job completion and in this tWarn you can pass all details as a message (concatenated string) and this tWarn you can catch in your tLogcatcher and based on message code you can decide its a info message and handle it differently

Comment: @Aniket did you find an acceptable solution ?